# React-Typescript - Logic on fetching a value and adding it to a new const in another react file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and Typescript. I'm using Material-UI and trying to display different components that will work independently of each other. While the navigation is displayed   I want to change the margin of all other elements so that their container(div) increases its margin (left) with help of a class where the styling gets the margin value which changes once the navigation is back to being hidden.
I've been stuck with a simple thing for a few days now. How do I get the different values from file A into a const in file B?

Among many other things I've tried:

This two display the wanted value that I've stored in a useState
  `const [data, setData] = useState(100);`
inside a exported function Aa; Letter 'A' meaning file A and letter 'a' meaning function 1.

```
    <div> {data} </div>
    <SetMargin value={data}/>
```

Here I try to export the other function Ab :

```
    export function SetMargin({value} : any) {
        return (
            <p>{value}</p>
        )
    }
```

On file B

I have function Ba with return containing

```
<Aa/>
<Ab/>
<Ca/>
<Da/>
```

And here is the thing
`<Aa/>` display the value inside a `<p>` tag changing for every click whereas `<Ab/>` does not. `<Ab/>` does it only when inside `<Aa>` like in the code above when adding the data value.

My goal is to put that number into a const in file B.

```
    const addNewValue = 100 //which it'll be different each time nav is opened/closed

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        appBar: {marginLeft: addNewValue}
    }))
```

The class is being used like this:

```
    <div className={classes.appBar}>
      <Ca/>
    </div>
```

Lastly, the `<p> {value} <p>` is never to be displayed. LOL crazy React ^_^
Thank you!

[image: Inside the whale]

Comment: can't you just use a `ThemeProvider`?

Comment: Hello @LindaPaiste, thank you for the tips! As I said I'm new to this React thing :P ThemeProvider sounds like a very good thing. I go learn and test how it works!